# Change image in models - Django

Tags: django, model

I wonder what is the best way to process images in Django.

Personally, I usually use [django-resized](https://pypi.org/project/django-resized/) but I came across some restrictions. I have a Masonry layout in the app. Is there a way to limit the size of my photo, for example, to 600 pixels wide (without cutting the photo on the length, just reduction)?

```
img = ResizedImageField(size=[800, 1200], crop=['middle', 'center'])
```

I mostly use the above code. But then my Masonry system will lose sense (each photo becomes of the same height and length).

I found an application like [sorl-thumbnail](https://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) but I did not find such a function to use in my model. If I do it in the template. My user can upload a huge photo that will be charged to the server. I don't see the point in storing extremely large photos.

My question is how to resize the image to 700 pixels(example) in my models.py file (without cropping it)?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:  by setting crop="noop" disabling cropping after the initial re-scaling of Wxh

```
{% thumbnail item.image "100x100" crop="noop" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```